How is $x_n$ bounded above by 3?
The original question was :
If $\left\{xn\right\}$ is a sequence defined inductively such that
$$x_1 = 1$$
And $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$x_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_n +2}$$
Prove that $\left\{ x_n \right\}$ converges and find it's limit.
I have already proved that $\left\{ x_n \right\}$ is a monotone increasing function and all I need to do to prove it's convergence is to just show that it's bounded above.
BUT! when I look up the proof online it has mentioned that $\left\{ x_n \right\}$ is bounded above by 3.
It has been bothering me. How did they got to this conclusion? What led them to this estimate? Because unfortunately, it's not very obvious to me.

What proof online?

That's not even the estimate I'd show.  It's easier to show $x_n \leq 2$ by induction on $n$.

This question is similar to: How to find out the possible limits of the following iteration?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (See the accepted answer.)

Hello @Ritik first you need to conclude for any k natural
$x_{k+1} \geq x_{k}$ then the conclusions follows since
$x_{n+1}^2={x_n}+2 \leq x_{n+1}+2 $ which shows indeed x_{n+1}\leq 2 for all n

The answer of Martin Argerami nails it.  For the record, an alternative (valid) argument is $~\displaystyle x_n \leq 3 \implies x_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_n + 2} \leq \sqrt{3 + 2} \leq 3.$

@Gonçalo it's an example in section 2.5 of the book "elements of real analysis" By Charles G. Denlinger.

If $x_n\leq2$, then
$$
x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n+2}\leq\sqrt{2+2}=2.
$$
This allows you to show by induction that $x_n\leq2$ for all $n$.
